# How to get the files in the upper level directory?

Tags: r

There are two files `c:/a/b/mycode.r` and `c:/a/myfunction.r` on my drive. When I run `mycode.r`, how to read the `myfunction.r` by using the relative path with `source()`? I tried `source("../myfunction.r")`, but it says ***No such file or directory***. How to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Try to set `chdir=TRUE`.
This will change the working directory to the directory of the file being sourced.

```
`source("../myfunction.r", chdir=TRUE)`
```

Comment: You are everywhere these days brother! Rock on :D

Comment: Lol. Hi Bro. I try to keep on learning. Best thing is the more I learn the more weired I am.

Comment: Yeah I was a bit busy with relocation so I haven't been around much for some days. I will be back even stronger. But it may be a good opportunity for revisiting some materials like `ggplot2`.